# Не разворачивается приложение на основе AlanJuden.MvcReportViewer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reportviewer

На Asp.net-core стандартный Report Viewer от Microsoft еще не работает (и не известно будет ли он перенесен). Нашлась альтернатива рекомендуемая одним из саппортов Microsoft [здесь](https://forums.asp.net/t/2117361.aspx). Да и все остальные рекомендации ведут на [этот же проект](https://github.com/alanjuden/MvcReportViewer). Но возникли проблемы решить которые не позволяет опыт - запуск примеров зависает на сборке проектов либо IIS сервер закрывается сразу после сборки. Кто нибудь сталкивался с этим?
Попробовал обновить все зависимости связанные с проектом, но что то обновилось до такой степени, что Core v1.x перестали поддерживать и требуется Core 2. Опять же из за этого не получается запустить примеры.